# Add new user data to div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn JavaScript. I have a question which might sound silly, but I would really appreciate the help.
I have the following code:

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function fn(){
    var Name = document.getElementById('name').value;       
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Name;
}    
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter">
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="fn()">click</button>
<div>
    <p id="result"></p>
</div>
</body>
```

I want to save every entry in of my textbox. Right If I am trying enter a new data input box, it replaces the previous data.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem;

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function fn(){
    var Name = document.getElementById('name').value;       
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += Name;
}    
</script>
```

notice the `+=` instead of `=`; 
it will get the previous value first, then add the new value to the end of it;

same as:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML + Name;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: what if instead of text, I want to have array of number from input and print all the user data in my result ID and also the sum of all the numbers?

Comment: @shubham how you are getting array of number from input? in string format? like `"[1,2,4,7]"`

Comment: `A var Num = [];
Num = document.getElementById('name').value;`

Comment: Can I write this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript code only the last attempt is saved. To save all the attempts try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function fn(){
    var Name = document.getElementById('name').value;       
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += Name +'<br/>';
}    
</script>
```

Every time button is clicked it will add new line symbol and new value to your result area, not relace previous try.

Comment: Thank you for the help